# Spring Data Elasticsearch with XML config does not work

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

I want to integrate ElasticSearch to an application that uses an old version  of spring, `3.0.4.RELEASE`.

In my `pom.xml`, I added the `2.1.3.RELEASE` version of `spring-data-elasticsearch`.

This application uses xml base configuration and here is how I define the elasticsearch configuration (`elasticSearchConfiguration.xml`) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">    

 <elasticsearch:repositories base-package="fr.myapp.search.repository" />
 <elasticsearch:transport-client id="data-api" cluster-nodes="localhost:9300" /></beans>
```

I also define my repo :

```
    package fr.myapp.search.repository;

import fr.myapp.search.document.MyDocument;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 * MyDocument
 */
public interface MyDocumentRepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<MyDocument, Long>
{

}
```

I am trying to use this repo in a service :

```
public class MyDocumentServiceImpl implements MyDocumentService
{
    @Autowired
    private MyDocumentRepo myDocumentRepo; 

    ...
}
```

The application is webapp bootstrapped with an `web.xml` :

```
<web-app 
    version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:/myApp.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>  
 ... 
</web-app>
```

`myApp.xml` is the main spring configuration that imports `elasticSearchConfiguration.xml`.

Whenever I launch the webapp, this exception always get raised :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [fr.myapp.service.search.repository.MyDocumentService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
```

Comment: I doubt that that is your full `web.xml` or that you are really using that to bootstrap the application.

Comment: You are totally correct, I put only the relevant information in the web.xml

Comment: Well you haven't as there is too little information.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?